# passing JSONGenerator apex value to javascript giving error

Tags: apex, visualforce, jsongenerator

I am trying to pass JSONGenerator value to javascript , but in vf page its appearing as new line due to which its erroring out "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" . Why in javascript its showing as new line, not as a one line string. The same in apex debug , its displaying as new line. How can I make it in a new line.

[image]

Apex -

```
 global static String getRelationshipMap(){
        lstWrap = new  List<wrapper>();
        List<Stakeholder__c> lstStakeHolders = [Select Id, Reporting_To__c,Reporting_To__r.Name, 
                                                External_Stakeholder__c, External_Stakeholder__r.Name  , Role__c
                                                FROM Stakeholder__c WHERE Id = 'a1g0E000005eLXpQAM'];
        JSONGenerator jsonGen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
       // jsonGen.writeStartObject();
        jsonGen.writeStartArray();        
        for(Stakeholder__c stk: lstStakeHolders) {
            jsonGen.writeStartObject();
            jsonGen.writeStringField('id',stk.Id);
            jsonGen.writeStringField('name',stk.External_Stakeholder__r.Name);
            if(stk.Reporting_To__c == null) {
                jsonGen.writeNullField('pid');
            }else{
                jsonGen.writeStringField('pid',stk.Reporting_To__c);
            }
            if(stk.Role__c == null) {
                jsonGen.writeNullField('title');
            }else{
                jsonGen.writeStringField('title',stk.Role__c); 
            }
            jsonGen.writeEndObject();
        }
        jsonGen.writeEndArray();
        //jsonGen.writeEndObject();
        jsonData = jsonGen.getAsString();
        System.debug('Json Data - ' + jsonData);
        return jsonData;
    }
```

VF page -

```
<apex:page doctype="html-5.0" standardStylesheets="false" controller="orgchartcontroller">
<script>

    var helloWord = "{!jsonData}"
</script>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge fields just do a literal string replacement. There's no syntax awareness. You must use [functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm#!) to correctly escape your data for the context in which you are merging it. In this case, you'll want `JSENCODE()`.